# An authorized user is not able to access a protected route

Tags: reactjs, jwt, authorization, mern

I am developing a MERN stack app. After a user successfully logs in, they can both view their tickets and create new tickets.

[image]

When a user clicks on the `View Tickets` button, a `GET` request is sent to the `/api/users/tickets` route, which is a protected route. So only logged in users can access it.

However, when I click on the `View Tickets` button (after logging in), I get an error message that says `Not Authorized, No token`. How is this possible? I am already logged in.
[image]

I am sending the JWT on every request header using Axios global defaults. Here is my `App.js` code snippet:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";
import { updateName } from "./components/clientState/authSlice";
import Home from "./components/screens/Home";
import Header from "./components/screens/Header";
import Login from "./components/screens/Login";
import Register from "./components/screens/Register";
import Tickets from "./components/screens/Tickets";
import SingleTicket from "./components/screens/SingleTicket";
import NewTicket from "./components/screens/NewTicket";
import PrivateRoute from "./components/screens/PrivateRoute";

const App = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    const tokenObj = localStorage.getItem("authStatus")
      ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("authStatus"))
      : null;

    if (tokenObj) {
      const { token } = tokenObj;
      axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${token}`;
      const { username } = jwt_decode(token);
      dispatch(updateName(username));
    }
  }, [dispatch]);
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />
        <Route path="/tickets/:id" element={<SingleTicket />} />
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
        <Route path="/new-ticket" element={<PrivateRoute />}>
          <Route path="/new-ticket" element={<NewTicket />} />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/tickets" element={<PrivateRoute />}>
          <Route path="/tickets" element={<Tickets />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Here are my ticket routes:

ticketRoutes.js

```
const express = require("express");
const { requireAuth } = require("../middleware/authMiddleware");

const {
  userTickets,
  userTicket,
  createUserTicket,
  deleteUserTicket,
} = require("../controllers/ticketControllers");

const router = express.Router();

router.get("/api/users/tickets", requireAuth, userTickets);
router.get("/api/users/tickets/:id", requireAuth, userTicket);
router.post("/api/users/tickets/create", requireAuth, createUserTicket);
router.delete("/api/users/tickets/:id", requireAuth, deleteUserTicket);

module.exports = router;
```

And here is my auth middleware:

authMiddleware.js

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const asyncHandler = require("express-async-handler");
const User = require("../models/userModel");
const createError = require("http-errors");

const requireAuth = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  let token;

  if (
    req.headers.authorization &&
    req.headers.authorization.startsWith("Bearer")
  ) {
    try {
      token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];
      console.log(token);
      const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
      req.user = await User.findById(decoded.id);
      next();
    } catch (err) {
      next(err);
    }
  }

  if (!token) {
    const err = createError(401, "Not Authorized. No Token");
    next(err);
  }
});

module.exports = { requireAuth };
```

What am I doing wrong? Also note that this problem was not always there. Started recently.

Comment: Check request headers in the browser's dev tools network tab, to ensure the token is being set correctly.

Comment: What changed since recently? If you are using some VCS like git, you can try doing some [bisect](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect) to find out. Maybe this will point you into some direction?

Comment: @IrfanullahJan The Authorization header is set after I refresh the tickets page and everything works fine. Does this mean I have to send the request header in a config object while making the axios request?